# The real solution from a system of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, roots, cubics

I found this question from my friend's math competition, I don't know where I must start it

There are 3 couples of real numbers $$(x_1,y_1) (x_2,y_2)$$ and $$(x_3, y_3)$$ that satisfies the system of equation :
$$x³-3xy²=2010 , y³-3x²y=2009$$
Find the value of $$\left(1-\frac{x_1}{y_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_2}{y_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_3}{y_3}\right)$$

Comment: Is this right so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

In the homogeneous polynomial

$$
p(x,y)=a x^3+b x^2y+c x y^2+d y^3 = 0
$$

making $\lambda = \frac xy$ and substituting we have

$$
(a\lambda^3+b\lambda^2+c\lambda + d)y^3 = 0
$$

so assuming $y \ne 0$ we have

$$
a\lambda^3+b\lambda^2+c\lambda + d = 0
$$

and for each pair $x_i,y_i$ we have

$$
a\lambda_i^3+b\lambda_i^2+c\lambda_i + d = 0
$$

now

$$
(1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_3) = 1 -(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)+(\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2\lambda_3)-\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3
$$

but by Vieta's formulas

$$
\frac ba = -(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)\\
\frac ca = (\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_2\lambda_3)\\
\frac da = -\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3
$$

hence

$$
(1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_3) = 1+\frac ba+\frac ca+\frac da = 1+\frac{b+c+d}{a}
$$

Comment: I dont understand subt 4 part

Comment: @user644938 I hope now it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We substitute $$y=tx$$ then we get
$$x^3(1-3t^2)=2010$$
$$x^3(t^3-3t)=2009$$
Dividing both equations we get
$$2009(1-3t^2)=2010(t^3-3t)$$
This is a polynomial in degree three. Can you solve this equation?

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$2009(x^3-3xy^2)=2010(y^3-3x^2y)$$ or
$$2009x^3+6030x^2y-6027xy^2-2010y^3=0,$$ which by the Viete's theorem gives
$$\left(1-\frac{x_1}{y_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_2}{y_2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x_3}{y_3}\right)=$$
$$=1+\frac{6030}{2009}-3-\frac{2010}{2009}=\frac{2}{2009}.$$